# Inbox and achievement notification alerts stay alert too long

Tags: bug, notifications, top-bar, global-inbox

The red inbox alert is a real attention and eye catcher. So whenever I see this red on the screen, I assume there is something to look at.  However, the alert does not go away or reappears after having clicked on it leading to false alerts in the following situations:

1. When there is both an inbox and notification alert, the red remains thereby suggesting that another message arrived.
2. When I do a "back" in the browser, the flashy red reappears - sometimes.

Comment: The back button issues on Stack Exchange are well known and not considered a bug; just reload the page if you use the back button; the inbox icon is not the only issue there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This is a pity, for it is really irritating.

Comment: When the alert is clicked, it disappears on deselection.  But if you mouse off of it to the side instead, it stays.

Comment: @Pokechu22: But that is a bug, right?

Comment: @false I'd say it's a bug, at least partially.  But the purpose of that comment was more to describe how to reproduce.  In any case, you can make it disappear by clicking on the icon a second time to hide it rather than moussing off.

Comment: @Pokechu22: It also means that the arrival of messages after having clicked on the mailbox is not indicated, yes?

Comment: *Not considered a bug* - by whom? Users or SE programmers/designers? Have you polled the users?